# How can I calculate a discrete Cumulative Distribution MultiDimensional Array from a discrete Probability Mass Array when dimensions > 2?

Tags: matlab, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, high-dimensional

I would appreciate any help in trying to calculate the Cumulative Distribution Array of a Probability Mass Array when dimensions > 2, essentially a discrete joint cumulative distribution from a sample of data.  MATLAB syntax would be most preferred.  In a bivariate case (2 dimensions), the following works well:
`cumsum(cumsum(epdf,1),2)./total`, where `cumsum` calculates the cumulative sum across the first and second dimensions.

Unfortunately, `cumsum` doesn't support more than 2 dimensions, at least from what I can tell.  The following is a simple 3D PDF I'm testing on in MATLAB.  Thank you for any suggestions.

```
ePDF(1,1,1) = 1;
ePDF(2,1,1) = 2;
ePDF(1,2,1) = 3;
ePDF(2,2,1) = 4;
ePDF(1,1,2) = 5;
ePDF(2,1,2) = 6;
ePDF(1,2,2) = 7;
ePDF(2,2,2) = 8;
total = 36;
```

Edit:  I found an N-Dimensional CumSum function from the open source program FreeMat which does exactly what I need.  Is there a way to replicate this function easily in Matlab?
http://freemat.sourceforge.net/help/elementary_cumsum.html

Comment: Silly me.  Just in case someone else is wondering about this, recursively calling the cumsum function for each dimension is the answer:
CDF = cumsum(ePDF,1);
CDF = cumsum(CDF,2);
CDF = cumsum(CDF,3);

Comment: user2038485 - Would you please turn your comment into an answer (possibly expanding on why you understand this to be the case so it's a bit more than two lines), so (among other things) I can upvote it?

Answer (score 0):

(Just repeating my comment as the answer here)

The solution is to recursively call the cumsum function for each dimension:

```
CDF = cumsum(ePDF,1);
CDF = cumsum(CDF,2);
CDF = cumsum(CDF,3);
```